# FAILED: ninja: 'out/host/darwin-x86/bin/brillo_update_payload' when I want to "make otapackage" in AOSP on Macbook M1

Tags: android, macos, android-source

I'm now build the AOSP project on Macbook(M1), after serval steps to setup the environment. I can build it successfully.

in the root dir:

```
source build/envsetup.sh 
lunch
m
```

after serval hours later, it can build successfully

```
[ 99% 100092/100137] Target Java: out/target/common/obj/APPS/Dialer_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar
Note: Generating a Provider for com.android.dialer.glidephotomanager.impl.GlidePhotoManagerImpl. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
Note: [1] Wrote GeneratedAppGlideModule with: []
[100% 100137/100137] Target vbmeta image: out/target/product/sunfish/vbmeta.img

#### build completed successfully (04:59:43 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcMT4.png)

and i want to build ota package with "make otapackage"

I know `otatools` is disabled on darwin (`build/make/core/Makefile`).
So i change the Makefile to enable the otatools:

```
ifeq ($(BUILD_OS),darwin)
  build_ota_package := true
  build_otatools_package := true
else
```

after re-build again(make sure build successfully) and run `make otapackage`

```
> make otapackage
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_sunfish
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-21.6.0-x86_64-12.6
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QD4A.200805.003
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/google/sunfish hardware/google/av hardware/google/interfaces hardware/google/pixel hardware/qcom/sm7150 hardware/qcom/sm7150/display vendor/google/camera vendor/qcom/sm7150 vendor/google/interfaces vendor/qcom/sm8150/codeaurora/telephony/ims vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/data/permissions vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/qcril-data-hal/qdp vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/qcril-data-hal/util vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/qcril-data-hal/datamodule vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/qcril-hal
============================================
wildcard(out/target/product/sunfish/clean_steps.mk) was changed, regenerating...
FAILED: ninja: 'out/host/darwin-x86/bin/brillo_update_payload', needed by 'out/target/product/sunfish/aosp_sunfish-ota-eng.kohleradmin.zip', missing and no known rule to make it
16:09:01 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:39 (mm:ss)) ####
```

so how to solve this issue or is it possible to build ota package on Macbook?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found we can't build otapackage on MacBook, I changed the environment to Ubuntu, and it works finally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).